# jquery css height setting not functioning properly

Tags: jquery, css, height

I'm trying to use some jQuery to set the left and right columns of my product and catalog pages (with a class of `.columns`) to the height of my `#detail` `<div>` which has some data pulled from a SQL database.

So, I am using this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  detailHeight = $('#detail').css('height');
  columnHeight = detailHeight + 10;

  $('.columns').css('height', columnHeight 'px');

});
```

My page is here: http://www.marioplanet.com/product.asp?IDnum=1

For some reason, the heights are not coming out properly..

Any ideas as to why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You have a typo here:

```
$('.columns').css('height', columnHeight 'px');
```

The `+` is missing:

```
$('.columns').css('height', columnHeight + 'px');
```

---

But, as pointed out by others, using the `css()` function to access the height of an element is wrong for your code as it returns and expects a string with a CSS unit after the numeric value. Therefore you're not really adding numbers but concatenating strings. That's why your code doesn't work.

To fix your code, use jQuery's convenience method [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height) for getting and setting the height of an element as a numeric value instead. Simply pass in your number as the argument when setting it:

```
  detailHeight = $('#detail').height();
  columnHeight = detailHeight + 10;

  $('.columns').height(columnHeight);
```

Comment: This, in addition the the fact that the columnHeight variable is `20px10px` when passed in that function.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Is there any reason that the heights still seem to be semi-skewed?  Thanks again so much, how could I forget such a wonderful method??? :D

Comment: @BOSS: what do you mean by semi-skewed? The columns look fine to me, unless you're referring to the icons where I *do* see a bit of an offset.

Comment: Check out this (http://www.marioplanet.com/product.asp?IDnum=1) product. Why is there spill on the #detail <div>?  The columns do look great though.

Comment: @BOSS: what browser are you testing on?

Comment: Safari 5 Mac, and iOS4 Safari xD

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `.height()` or even `.attr("height")`?

Comment: `attr("height")` doesn't work because `height` isn't an HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  detailHeight = $('#detail').css('height'); // would return something like 25px...
  columnHeight = detailHeight + 10; // 25px + 10 == ??

  $('.columns').css('height', columnHeight + 'px'); // ===>> .css('height', '25px10' + 'px');

});
```

suggestion,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  detailHeight = $('#detail').height(); // use .height()
  columnHeight = detailHeight + 10; 

  $('.columns').css('height', columnHeight + 'px');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has mentioned the missing '+' symbol in the last statement, but when I ran alert() on the variable columnHeight (using my example) it showed 20px10. I wrapped detailHeight inside a parseInt() and it worked.

HTML Snippet

```
<div id="detail" style="background:#aaa;">HELLO</div>
<div id="x" class="columns" style="background:#f00;">HELLO</div>
```

JS Snippet

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  detailHeight = $('#detail').css('height');
  columnHeight = parseInt(detailHeight) + 10;

  $('.columns').css('height', columnHeight+'px');
});
```